# Difference between regular clustering and k-means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-computing, k-means

I have a set of N values and I perform the following two operations on them

1) Sort and iterate and partition the values into k buckets.

2) Run the Lloyd's algorithm (as given [here](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=k-means.clustering)) and get k means.

Can someone please explain the physical significance and difference between the two results?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In #2 k means establishes a Voronoi diagram which provides partitions for classifying instances. You can think of each partition as a "bucket" for #1.

Your description of #1 doesn't really describe an algorithm so in a vague way there isn't a difference between the two descriptions.